# pHp function - Remove all line breaks and html entities from a string?

Tags: php, html

I have descriptions from a database that are originally written using HTML tags like so:

```
&#149; Description bullet blah blah
<br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah
<br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah
```

In the near future, I will be stripping all HTML from the database descriptions and employ javascript to render the formatting. In the meantime, though, I need a simple function that will strip all of the breaks and bullets.

I have this which takes care of the breaks:

```
str_replace('<br />', ' ', $row_rsDetails['Description'])
```

Can't figure out how to work in removal of the hex bullets without breaking the function, though. I have searched, maybe I missed an answer. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: If they're already in your DB, why not just [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) them all in there instead? Hit 2 posts with one stone, as it were ;-) why do twice the work?

Comment: Please clarify - your title is more general _all line breaks and html entities_ but in the question you specifically mention removing only the bullets. Are there more entities to remove, or only the bullets?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: This is just a bandaid for presentation purposes, I will be taking care of things on the database end pretty soon.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: A few of the descriptions do have other html entities, the particular example I posted has only bullets and breaks, though. I think I can figure out how to neutralize the others from this point, though. (See my comment above.) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `array` in `str_replace`:

```
$result = str_replace(array('<br />', '&#149;'), ' ', $row_rsDetails['Description']);
```

Comment: Yep, thought I missed something easy. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another option (similar to @AbraCadaver's) is to write out each `str_replace` on a new line:

```
$string = '&#149; Description bullet blah blah
<br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah
<br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah';

$string = str_replace('<br />', ' ', $string);
$string = str_replace('&#149;', ' ', $string);


echo $string;
```

Comment: `str_replace()` will happily receive an array of needle strings as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove these html entities:

```
<?php
    $string = '&#149; Description bullet blah blah
    <br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah
    <br /> &#149; Description bullet blah blah';
    $pattern = '/&#\d+;/i';
    $replacement = '';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Are you making the `&`, the `#`, the digit characters, or the `,` case-insensitive in your pattern???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way to treat all hex chars is to consider [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

```
$result = rawurldecode( $string );
```

This will decode all hex-escaped strings into their native characters.

Also regarding the `<br />` tags, have you considered using

```
$s2 = preg_replace('<br[^>]*/?>', ' ', $original);
$s3 = preg_replace('</br>', ' ', $s2); // if br tag with explicit closing tag
```

The same would apply to `<p>` tags.
Both regular expressions are not really HTML-compliant (for example they would not match `<br class="fo>o"/>` correctly). There is a lot of information already regarding matching HTML tags in regexp on StackOverflow. If your XML input is hardcoded, it might be worth considering though.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for more additional information.

Of course you can have arrays in preg_replace, too, as you would use in str_replace.

Comment: Why bother making the late slash optional if you are already using a greedy "non-greater-than" character class?